# Selector skips redux store updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, ag-grid

I have a grid in which are rows with data. I get liveNodes (new rows) from the server, which I add at the begin of grid and show for user. In my code it looks like this:

1. I get message from the server with information about new liveNode, after that I need to set it to the grid,  message name is `GRID.SET_NEW_LIVENODE`
2. My reducer catches this message, and update liveNode state:

```js
    const initState = {
       ...,
       liveNode: null,
    }

const setNewLiveNode = (state, { payload }) => {
  const newLiveNode = {
        ...payload,
        ...,
        ...,
  }

  return {
       ...state,
       liveNode: newLiveNode,
  }
}

const reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
        case GRID.SET_NEW_LIVENODE:
            return setNewLiveNode(state, action)
        default:
            return state
  }
}
```

3. My Reselect selector get updated liveNode from the redux store

```js
export const getLiveNode = createSelector(getState, state => state.liveNode)
```

4. In my grid I use useSelector and get updated liveNode into component. useEffect catch updates and push liveNode in the top of grid's list.

```html
const Grid = () => {
const liveNode = useSelector(getLiveNode)

useEffect(() => {
   gridList.api.push(liveNode)
}, [liveNode])
 

return  <GridList />
}
```

In cases when I have big amount of messages in a small amount of time, for example 100 messages in  3-7 seconds, my selector skips redux store updates, it means:

I get 100 messages = 100 liveNodes => redux store was updated 100 times , but selector was called only 97, 98, sometimes 100 (on every case different value, I can't  find any regularity, sometimes it works correct, it is non-predictable). And in grid was added only 97 or 98 liveNodes instead of 100, that is not good.

It works pretty good, then I have small amount of messages 1, 3, 5

So I can make a conclusion, that selector skips redux store updates then I have big amount of updates per moment.
In console I get a warning: ***Application state or actions payloads are too large making Redux DevTools serialization slow***

What is the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: React-Redux will try to batch some re-renders to optimize behavior. Depending on where and when you are dispatching these updates, it's very possible that some of them are being batched.  However, the end result _should_ show all the actual data that exists at the end.  Answering this more specifically would require seeing a demo that shows this problem happening.  Is the store state actually correct at the end?

Comment: My problem is: in store I save only one node - new node, so when I get new node I rewrite last one with a new one, like this:
` return {
       ...state,
       liveNode: newLiveNode,
  }`

Because of this batch I skip liveNodes, for example instead of 3 updates I get only last update with last liveNode and in the end  I add to the grid only last liveNode instead of 3 liveNodes.

There is an option to turn off react-redux batch behavior?

Sorry, to show a demo it would be very difficult. If this description is not enough, I will make a demo. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it's really not clear what the exact behavior is here, and I'd really need to get hands-on with a demo to understand what you're trying to describe, and be able to suggest a potential solution.

Comment: @ДядяФея I'm having the same problem. Did you get it fixed?